# Ant build.xml $$

Tags: ant, build

I have a Ant build.xml that does a check as below, i was just wondering what the $$ signifies?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
 <equals casesensitive="false" arg1="${subPlan}" arg2="$${subPlan}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ant manual [Properties and PropertyHelpers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) :

```
..Ant will expand the text $$ to a single $ and suppress the normal property expansion mechanism..
```

It's often used for output like that :

```
<property name="foo" value="bar"/>

<echo>$${foo} => ${foo}</echo>
```

output :

```
[echo] ${foo} => bar
```

In your case it checks whether a property with the name subPlan is set within your project, as ${subPlan} won't be expanded if it doesn't exist, f.e. :

```
<project>
 <property name="subPlan" value="whatever"/>
 <echo>${subPlan}</echo>
</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] whatever
```

whereas :

```
<project>
 <echo>${subPlan}</echo>
</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] ${subPlan}
```

It's actually possible to set the propertyvalue for Property subPlan to ${subPlan} :

```
<property name="subPlan" value="$${subPlan}"/>
```

but that doesn't make sense, so your snippet does a combined check => is Property subPlan set and has a useful value ? could be used like that :

```
<fail message="Property not set or invalid value !">
 <condition>
  <equals casesensitive="false" arg1="${subPlan}" arg2="$${subPlan}"/>
 </condition>
</fail>
```

Finally the standard way to check whether a property is set is using the [isset condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html), f.e. :

```
<fail message="Property not set !">
 <condition>
  <not>
   <isset property="subPlan"/>
  </not>
 </condition>
</fail>
```